# How do I add a red asterisk to form fields that fail to validate?

Tags: django, django-forms

If a form field fails to validate, Django will display a helpful message (e.g. "This field is required"). However, in addition to the helpful message, I also want to display a red asterisk next to the form field itself if there are any validation errors for the field. Something like:

[image: Form field]

Excerpt from my template:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I know I can insert the asterisk using [manual form rendering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually), but I am looking for a way to do this without editing the template. Is there a way to do this? Perhaps it can be done by overriding specific `django.forms.Form` methods?

Comment: What about adding an asterisk to label text?

Comment: @DavitTovmasyan I only want the asterisk to appear if the field fails validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `error_css_class` [attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#styling-required-or-erroneous-form-rows) to the `Form` and when a field has an error, this attribute's value will be added to the field's wrapper html classes (`p` in this case).

Then in your css you can add a rule like:

```css
.error_css_class input::after {
    content: "*";
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but I am primarily looking for server-side solutions.